# How do I find speed at a given point in time given the acceleration

Tags: physics

I have the acceleration and the time elapsed. Say the acceleration is 5m/s^2. 
I need to find the speed at second 3. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well, what do you know about the relation between speed and acceleration?

Comment: As you can probably guess I am taking physics I. I have checked every reference I have, and have found nothing concerning this matter. So, nothing I suppose.

Comment: Just assume I know nothing

Comment: Do you know what *acceleration* is? Just the definition?

Comment: OK, then: acceleration is the derivative, with respect to time, of the speed. So now the question is, what do you know about derivatives and antiderivatives?

Comment: Yes, of course. It is the rate at which speed increases.

Comment: @gerrymyerson could you simplify the terms you are using

Comment: Ok, so when you said that you know nothing about the relation between the two, that probably wasn't very true. Regardless: Something increases by 5 units a second for 3 seconds. What's the result?

Comment: @user296602 I'm an idiot. Thank you for the answer. Please post this as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @RamiroRocha You can write this as an answer and post it yourself if you'd like; it would be good practice.

Answer (score 1):

$acceleration(t)=\frac{\delta V(t)}{\delta t}$

$\implies V(t)=\int aceleration(s) ds= \int \frac{5m}{s^2} ds = \frac{-5m}{s}+C$

With C an initial condition?